# What features of Xamarin Forms should I use to achieve "3D" rotation, like Instagram

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

Instagram uses a 3D rotation when switching between users in some parts of the app as shown below.

[image]

I've been experimenting with Xamarin Forms

- Transitions
- Animations
- Skia Sharp

but have been unable to recreate this on Xamarin. What are the correct set of technologies to get a full screen rotation on Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to resort to custom renderers and implement something like this in C#: https://github.com/katleta3000/RotateController (this example is in Swift for iOS, possibly something similar exists for Android as well).

It's not possible in pure Xamarin Forms to my knowledge.

This is how the provided example would look like in C# (note: I have not tested the outcome, hence the two TODO's in the following code):

```cs
// Example Swift code licensed by MIT license. Converted to C#.
// Original author: katleta3000

using System;
using CoreAnimation;
using UIKit;

namespace MyProject.iOS
{
    public enum RotationDirection : int
    {
        Right = 0, 
        Left
    }

    public enum RotationType : int
    {
        Push = 0,
        Pop
    }

    class FCBlackBackgroundView : UIView
    {

    }

    class FCRotateLayer : CALayer
    {
    }

    public class RotatingController : UINavigationController
    {
        public void PushViewController(UIViewController controller, RotationDirection rotateDirection) {
            Perform3DRotate(RotationType.Push, rotateDirection, controller);
        }

        public void PopViewController(RotationDirection rotateDirection) {
            Perform3DRotate(RotationType.Pop, rotateDirection, null);
        }

        // MARK: - private

        private void Perform3DRotate(RotationType type, RotationDirection rotateDirection, UIViewController controller) {
            var layer = RotationLayer();

            var cube = CubeTransform(rotateDirection, layer: layer);

            if (type == RotationType.Push) {
                this.PushViewController(controller, animated: false);
            } else if (type == RotationType.Pop) {
                this.PopViewController(animated: false);
            }
            layer.AddSublayer(LayerFromView(this.View, transform: cube));

            this.View.AddSubview(BackgroundView(UIColor.White));

            this.View.Layer.AddSublayer(layer);

            layer.AddAnimation(RotationAnimation(rotateDirection), "rotate");

        }

        private CATransform3D CubeTransform(RotationDirection rotateDirection, CALayer layer)
        {
            var cube = CATransform3D.MakeTranslation(0, 0, 0);

            layer.AddSublayer(LayerFromView(this.View, transform: cube));

            cube.Rotate(Radians(90), 0, 1, 0);

            cube.Translate(CubeSize(), 0, 0);

            if (rotateDirection == RotationDirection.Left) {
                cube.Rotate(Radians(90), 0, 1, 0);

                cube.Translate(CubeSize(), 0, 0);

                cube.Rotate(Radians(90), 0, 1, 0);

                cube.Translate(CubeSize(), 0, 0);

            }
            return cube;

        }

        private FCRotateLayer RotationLayer()
        {
            FCRotateLayer layer = new FCRotateLayer();

            layer.Frame = this.View.Frame;

            layer.AnchorPoint = new CoreGraphics.CGPoint(0.5, 0.5);

            CATransform3D transform = CATransform3D.Identity;

            transform.m34 = 1.0f / -750;

            layer.SublayerTransform = transform;

            return layer;

        }

        private CAAnimation RotationAnimation(RotationDirection direction) 
        {
            CATransaction.Flush();

            var animationGroup = new CAAnimationGroup();

            animationGroup.Duration = 0.4;

            CABasicAnimation rotation = null;
            CABasicAnimation translationX = null;

            if (direction == RotationDirection.Right) {
                rotation = CABasicAnimation.FromKeyPath("sublayerTransform.rotation.y");

                rotation.To = FromObject(Radians(-90));

                translationX = CABasicAnimation.FromKeyPath("sublayerTransform.translation.x");

                translationX.To = FromObject(-TranslationForAnimation());

            }
            else if (direction == RotationDirection.Left) {
                rotation = CABasicAnimation.FromKeyPath("sublayerTransform.rotation.y");

                rotation.To = FromObject(Radians(90));

                translationX = CABasicAnimation.FromKeyPath("sublayerTransform.translation.x");

                translationX.To = FromObject(TranslationForAnimation());

            }

            var translationZ = CABasicAnimation.FromKeyPath("sublayerTransform.translation.z");

            translationZ.To = FromObject(-TranslationForAnimation());

            animationGroup.Animations = new CAAnimation[] { rotation, translationX, translationZ };

            animationGroup.FillMode = CoreAnimation.CAFillMode.Forwards; //TODO: maybe convert nsstring to string

            animationGroup.RemovedOnCompletion = false;

            //TODO: unsubscribe necessary?
            animationGroup.AnimationStopped += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var layers = this.View.Layer.Sublayers;
                if (layers != null) {
                    foreach (var layer in layers) {
                        if (layer is FCRotateLayer) {
                            layer.RemoveFromSuperLayer();
                        }
                    }
                }
                foreach(var view in this.View.Subviews) {
                    if (view is FCBlackBackgroundView) {
                        view.RemoveFromSuperview();
                    }
                }
            };

            animationGroup.TimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.FromName(CAMediaTimingFunction.EaseInEaseOut);

            return animationGroup;
        }

        private CALayer LayerFromView(UIView view) {
            var rect = CoreGraphics.CGRect.FromLTRB(0, 0, this.View.Bounds.Size.Width, this.View.Frame.Size.Height);

            CALayer imageLayer = new CALayer();

            imageLayer.AnchorPoint = new CoreGraphics.CGPoint(1, 1);

            imageLayer.Frame = rect;
            UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(view.Frame.Size, false, UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale);
            var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
            if (context != null) {
                view.Layer.RenderInContext(context);
            }
            UIImage image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

            UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

            imageLayer.Contents = image.CGImage;
            return imageLayer;
        }

        private CALayer LayerFromView(UIView view, CATransform3D transform) {
            var layer = LayerFromView(view);

            layer.Transform = transform;
            return layer;
        }

        private FCBlackBackgroundView BackgroundView(UIColor color)
        {
            var view = new FCBlackBackgroundView
            {
                Frame = this.View.Frame
            };

            view.BackgroundColor = color;
            return view;
        }

        private float Radians(float degrees) {
            return degrees * (float)Math.PI / 180;
        }

        private nfloat TranslationForAnimation() {
            return CubeSize() / 2;
        }

        private nfloat CubeSize() {
            return UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C# version of the linked swift controller. Some things I couldn't translate from Swift.  Would be great if anyone can verify/think through the number conversions.

```
using CoreAnimation;
using CoreGraphics;
using UIKit;


namespace hackettyHack
{
    public enum RotationDirection //int
    {
        // case Right = 0, Left
        Right,
        Left
    }
    public enum RotationType //int
    {
        // case Push = 0, Pop   }
        Push,
        Pop
    }


    class FCBlackBackgroundView : UIView
    {

    }

    class FCRotateLayer : CALayer
    {
    }

    public class RotatingController : UINavigationController
    {
        public void PushViewController(UIViewController controller, RotationDirection rotateDirection)
        {
            Perform3DRotate(RotationType.Push, rotateDirection, controller);
        }
        public void PopViewController(UIViewController controller, RotationDirection rotateDirection)
        {
            Perform3DRotate(RotationType.Pop, rotateDirection, controller);
        }

        void Perform3DRotate(RotationType rotationType, RotationDirection rotateDirection, UIViewController v)
        {
            var layer = RotationLayer();

            var cube = CubeTransform(rotateDirection, layer);

            switch (rotationType)
            {
                case RotationType.Pop:
                    this.PopViewController(animated: false);
                    break;
                case RotationType.Push:
                    this.PushViewController(this, animated: false); //todo: make sure the SWIFT line below for controller! means THIS
                                                                    // self.pushViewController(controller!, animated: false)
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            layer.AddSublayer(LayerFromView(this.View, cube));

            this.View.AddSubview(BackgroundView(UIColor.White));

            this.View.Layer.AddSublayer(layer);

            layer.AddAnimation(RotationAnimation(rotateDirection), forkey: "rotate");//FIXME  parameter
        }

        CATransform3D CubeTransform(RotationDirection rotateDirection, CALayer layer)
        {
            var cube = CATransform3D.MakeTranslation(0, 0, 0);//FIXME and all below

            layer.AddSublayer(LayerFromView(this.View, transform: cube);

            cube = CATransform3D.Rotate(cube, CGFloat(radians(90)), 0, 1, 0);

            cube = CATransform3D.Translate(cube,CubeSize(), 0, 0);
            if (rotateDirection == RotationDirection.Left)
            {
                cube = CATransform3D.Rotate(cube, CGFloat(radians(90)), 0, 1, 0);

                cube = CATransform3D.Translate(cube, CubeSize(), 0, 0);

                cube = CATransform3D.Rotate(cube, CGFloat(radians(90)), 0, 1, 0);

                cube = CATransform3D.Translate(cube, CubeSize(), 0, 0);

            }
            return cube;
        }

        FCRotateLayer RotationLayer()
        {
            var layer = new FCRotateLayer();

            layer.Frame = this.View.Frame;

            layer.AnchorPoint = new CoreGraphics.CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5);

            CATransform3D transform = CATransform3D.Identity;

            transform.m34 = 1 / -750;

            layer.SublayerTransform = transform;

            return layer;
        }

        CAAnimation RotationAnimation(RotationDirection direction)
        {
            CATransaction.Flush();

            var animationGroup = new CAAnimationGroup();

            animationGroup.Duration = 0.4;

            var rotation = new CABasicAnimation();
            var translationX = new CABasicAnimation();

            if (direction == RotationDirection.Right)
            {
                rotation = new CABasicAnimation() { KeyPath = "sublayerTransform.rotation.y" };

                //rotation.To   = NSNumber(float: radians(-90))//FIXME

                translationX = new CABasicAnimation() { KeyPath = "sublayerTransform.rotation.x" };

                    translationX.To = NSNumber(float: Float(TranslationForAnimation()));//FIXME
            }
            else if (direction == RotationDirection.Left)
            {
                rotation = new CABasicAnimation() { KeyPath = "sublayerTransform.rotation.y" };

                //rotation.To = NSNumber(float: radians(90))//FIXME

                translationX = new CABasicAnimation() { KeyPath = "sublayerTransform.rotation.x" };

                translationX.To = NSNumber(float: Float(TranslationForAnimation()));//FIXME
            }
            var translationZ = new CABasicAnimation() { KeyPath = "sublayerTransform.translation.z" };

            translationZ.To = NSNumber(float: Float(TranslationForAnimation()));//FIXME

            animationGroup.Animations = new CAAnimation[3] { rotation, translationX, translationZ };

            animationGroup.FillMode = kCAFillModeForwards; /// //FIXME TBD what is the constant? where is it?

            animationGroup.RemovedOnCompletion = false;

            animationGroup.Delegate = this; // or should this be = to aiimationGroup? 

            animationGroup.TimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.FromName("kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut");

            return animationGroup;
        }

        CALayer LayerFromView(UIView view)
        {
            var rect = new CGRect(0, 0, this.View.Bounds.Size.Width, this.View.Bounds.Size.Height);

            var imageLayer = new CALayer();

            imageLayer.AnchorPoint = new CGPoint(1, 1);

            imageLayer.Frame = rect;

            UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(view.Frame.Size, false, UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale);

            // No idea how to convert "if..let..??" from swift.
            // 
            //if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {//FIXME
            //view.layer.renderInContext(context)
            //}
            UIImage image = new UIImage( = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();//FIXME

            UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

            imageLayer.Contents = image.CGImage;


            return imageLayer;
        }

        CALayer LayerFromView(UIView view, CATransform3D transform)
        {
            var layer = LayerFromView(view);
            layer.Transform = transform;
            return layer;
        }

        System.nfloat Radians(System.nfloat degrees)
        {
            return degrees * float(M_PI) / 180;  //FIXME
        }

        System.nfloat TranslationForAnimation()
        {
            return CubeSize() / 2;
        }

        System.nfloat CubeSize()
        {
            return UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
        }

        FCBlackBackgroundView BackgroundView(UIColor color)
        {
            var view = new FCBlackBackgroundView() { Frame = this.View.Frame };
            view.BackgroundColor = color;

            return view;
        }

    }
}


/*

public override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool)//FIXME no suitable overrride found
{
if let layers = self.view.layer.sublayers {
for layer in layers {
if layer.isKindOfClass(FCRotateLayer.classForCoder()) {
layer.removeFromSuperlayer()

}
}
}
for view in self.view.subviews {
if view.isKindOfClass(FCBlackBackgroundView.classForCoder()) {
view.removeFromSuperview()

}
}
}



* 
*/
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with the translated version. By the way, `animationDidStop` is actually an event in Xamarin (see [this documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.CoreAnimation.CAAnimationDelegate.AnimationStopped/p/MonoTouch.CoreAnimation.CAAnimation/System.Boolean/)).